# How do you explain the difference between 'place' and 'space'?

Tags: grammar, differences, nouns

I'm an English teacher myself (to foreign students), but a student of mine asked me this and I wasn't able to give a concise answer. Googling this came up with geography and philosophy results, when I just mean this in terms of grammar. I couldn't find anything on this stack exchange either.

I think space is usually uncountable, but a parking space is an exception. A place could refer to a building or a seat on a train or a place on a course.

Mistakes between them could be: 'I'm looking for a parking place' and 'There's no place in this room'.

But how would you clearly explain the difference between the two?

Comment: I think we have had a few questions about this topic....please do some research.

Comment: There's a whole lot more going on with these words than just countability. _Place_ is locative, whereas _space_ defines dimensionality. Probly the best place to start, since you're a teacher, is with Fillmore's [_Deixis Lectures_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html), which covers this among other topics.